# How to display the contents of a modal window on large screens?

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

What nonsense I wrote in the question, but I will try to explain)

How in bootstrap to implement a modal window by clicking on a button on small screens and ignore this modal window on large displays?

There is a product filter. It is always displayed on large screens. But on small screens, the content should be placed in a modal window and hidden. And it only shows up on the click of a button.

I couldn't find any other solution than to duplicate content and hide one content on small screens and other content on large screens. But of course this is wrong.

Perhaps there is another solution - with pleasure I will listen to your advice.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
    <i class="bi bi-funnel"></i>
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="X"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Content
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All code except content should be hidden on large screens.